# Redhat Pacemaker not able to authenticate in AWS EC2 on RHEL 9 HA

Tags: amazon-ec2, redhat, high-availability, pacemaker

Im trying to install and configure a High Availability Pacemaker Cluster in AWS EC2,
But for some reason it is unable to establish authentication between 2 nodes.
OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9 High Availability

The command that I run:
`pcs host auth mypc -u hacluster`

The error message obtainned is:
`Error: mypc: Username and/or password is incorrect`

I've tried to change the passwd of hacluster user, using `passwd hacluster`
I've tried to ssh as  hacluster user, which was successfull onto both machines.
The security group is open to all connections.
I can ssh from one machine to another.